# Node.js "exec" command not working with rundll32

Tags: node.js

I have a simple node server set up with the purpose of automatic image printing.

The code:

```
var directory =  process.env['USERPROFILE'] + '\\Downloads\\';
var command = 'rundll32 C:\\Windows\\System32\\shimgvw.dll ImageView_PrintTo /pt "' + directory + imageName + '" "EPSON TM-C3500"';
exec(command, function(error, stdout, stderr){});
```

the command string:

```
rundll32 C:\Windows\System32\shimgvw.dll ImageView_PrintTo /pt "C:\Users\gperry\Downloads\badge_0_12968249.jpg" "EPSON TM-C3500"
```

If I run that command in a cmd.exe process it works perfectly, but the exec command seems to do nothing at all... running other commands with exec like "mspaint /pt" work just fine, so I don't know what is going on here.

Help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Maybe use the dedicated [`print`](http://superuser.com/a/477910/507397) command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, for anybody who cares.

I changed the command to execute a call to a batch script which then called the print command.

```
var directory =  process.env['USERPROFILE'] + '\\Downloads\\';
var command = 'start cmd.exe /C ' + __dirname + '\\print.bat ' + directory + imageName + ' "EPSON TM-C3500"';
exec(command, {}, function(error, stdout, stderr){});
```

But then the batch script wasn't working... why? I don't know. I do know that adding a TIMEOUT 0 in the batch script fixed it.

```
TIMEOUT 0
rundll32 C:\\Windows\\System32\\shimgvw.dll ImageView_PrintTo /pt %*
```